# Fetch few records at a time

Tags: java, mysql

This question might be already answered, but I am not able to find a good one, I am trying to read data from one database and perform some operation and my source database is very huge like 100 million records or 100GB table it is, so I tried the below method to extract few records at a time so that I wont get memory exception but what I am getting is only the max records of what I set to setMaxRows(), like for example if I set 100, I am getting only 100 and I am testing this against the mysql database.

Here is my java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBCTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "root");
             conn.setAutoCommit(false);
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

             stmt.setMaxRows(100);
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from mydatabase.posthistory");
             int i=0;
             for (;;) {
                 System.out.println("Reading the set from: "+i);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        i++;
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                    if ((stmt.getMoreResults() == false) && (stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1)) {
                        System.out.println("End of reading.");
                        break;
                    }           
                }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong here. Any help or suggestions will be great. And I am using the mysql jsbc driver version 5.1.22. if I run it normally, then java is trying to bring the entire data into ram which throws me the error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: I would suggest to try JPA framework like Hibernate or Eclispelink and use the cursor functionality. That will create a stream of resultset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For particularly Mysql database use

```
    stmt = connection.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                        java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); 
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

For other databases

```
stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
```

This will not fetch whole database into ResultSet object.

Comment: if I keep stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);, how many records will I get at a time?

Comment: I am not sure how many records it loads at a time in mysql but it does not load whole data into resultset object. Keeps a pointer and loads data in a sequence. Did it resolved your issue?

Comment: Yes it has resolved my issue and the records are coming sequentially into result set.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Statement.setFetchSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-) to control the number of rows that are buffered. The default is 0 which can buffer the entire result, depending on the driver.

Note, the [MySQL JDBC option `useCursorFetch`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) should be enabled for `setFetchSize` to work. See [implementation notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

> Another alternative is to use cursor-based streaming to retrieve a set
>   number of rows each time. This can be done by setting the connection
>   property useCursorFetch to true, and then calling setFetchSize(int)
>   with int being the desired number of rows to be fetched each time:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/?useCursorFetch=true", "user", "s3cr3t"
);

stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.setFetchSize(100);
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM your_table_here");
```

[`Statement.setMaxRows`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows-int-) just limits the number of rows returned and causes excess rows to be discarded as you observed.

Comment: so if I set the setFetchSize, it will run the query but will get only 100 records at a time into the ram?, my issue is if java brings the entire records into ram it will throw an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: I am getting this error if I use setFetchSize, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".

Comment: Perhaps also enable `useCursorFetch`.